# Unable to generate clientId and secret SharePoint using appregnew url

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-app-registration

I am trying to generate ClientID and Secret in one of the SharePoint Portal using the _layouts/15/appregnew.aspx url.
But all the time while submitting it provides error such as "Something went wrong".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to enable ACS app-only access token:

"For new tenants, apps using an ACS app-only access token is disabled by default. We recommend using the Azure AD app-only model which is modern and more secure. But you can change the behavior by running ‘set-spotenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false' (needs the latest SharePoint admin PowerShell)."

[Granting access using SharePoint App-Only](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Do I need to have separate Azure license for the Azure AD app-only model ?

Comment: No, you can create an app registration in the default Azure AD tenant that comes with your Microsoft 365 subscription. If this answer helped, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted to help inform the community.